# How do I get my Android application login to a server?

Tags: php, android

I want to ask about the best way to let an Android application log in to a server (PHP). Do I have to use a session? I want to log in and send some information to the server and save that information in the database.

I currently use this:

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(path);
```

And then use JSON to send the data. I want a good way to verify the Android app identity to my server page.

Answer (score 1):

Not difficult. You don't really 'log in' per se with HTTP (the web's protocol), you open a one-time connection to perform your task. On Android you'll be looking at something like this:

```
        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://yourserver.com/yourpage.php");
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setRequestMethod("PUT");
            OutputStreamWriter output = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
            output.write(  // ... );
            output.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        // Handle error
    }
```

Comment: i am currently use this HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();and HttpPost post = new HttpPost(path);and use json to send a data ,but in my page(yourpage.php),i want a good way to verify the Android app identity.

Comment: You should reword your original question to clarify this.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to build an API.